# Add sound effect on splash screen with react native

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, react-native-cli

I'm trying to add a sound effect to my ** splash screen ** with react-native, which I already did with ** react-native-bootsplash **, but I don't know how to add a sound effect.
Thanks in advance, greetings ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-native-sound-player` to add sound to your splash screen.

`On iOS, drag and drop sound file into project in Xcode. Remember to check "Copy items if needed" option and "Add to targets".`

`On Android, put sound files in {project_root}/android/app/src/main/res/raw/. Just create the folder if it doesn't exist.`

```
import SoundPlayer from 'react-native-sound-player'

try {
    // play the file tone.mp3
    SoundPlayer.playSoundFile('tone', 'mp3')
    // or play from url
    SoundPlayer.playUrl('https://example.com/music.mp3')
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`cannot play the sound file`, e)
}
```